# File .pem Permission denied

Tags: openssl, curl

I have received from my partner a pfx file that I converted to pem for API

The idea is that I do not know where to put the ubuntu server and how to access the plug-in on the woocomerce

my log it's this

```
#Next GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 58: could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?) in /var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:51
Stack trace
0 /var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::wrapException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Message\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException))
/var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(132): GuzzleHttp\RequestFsm->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Transaction))
/var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): GuzzleHttp\RequestFsm->GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Array)
/var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
/var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/FutureResponse.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
/var/www/html/magazin/wp-content/plugins/wc-moldovaagroindbank/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(134): GuzzleHttp\Message\FutureResponse::proxy(Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureArray), Object(Closure))
```

Comment: It says `Permission denied` so you need to check your permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not comment so I need to answer.

I see 3 Points where it can fail:

1. File not Found
2. File Permission
3. Encrypted Key (wrong Passphrase)